# State update bug

Tags: reactjs

I have a bug trying to update state in React. here is my `setState` function:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
      songs: [],
  }

  handleUpload = (songData) => {
    var songs = [...this.state.songs, songData];
    console.log(songs);
    this.setState({songs});
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="">
        <SidebarTopOverlay
          onUpload={this.handleUpload}
          logo={logo}/>
```

and here is the result of console.log:

```
(1) […]
​
0: Object { title: "asdf", description: "", songFile: [], … }
​
length: 1
​
__proto__: Array []
App.js:19
(2) […]
​
0: Object { title: "asdfasdf", description: "", songFile: [], … }
​
1: Object { title: "asdfasdf", description: "", songFile: [], … }
​
length: 2
​
__proto__: Array []
```

as you can see, something directly overrides the state, since (edit) on the second log it should not print duplicates of the `songFields` to be added.

here is the UploadHandlers class:

```
import React from 'react';
import UploadDropdown from '../../presentational-components/uploader/uploadDropdown.js';


const initialState = {
  songUploadFields: {
    title: '',
    description: '',
    songFile: [],
    genres: [],
  },
  uploadButtonToggle: true,
}

class UploadHandlers extends React.Component{
  state = initialState;

  reset = () => {
    this.setState(initialState);
  }


  handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    var value = e.target.value;
    var songUploadFields = this.state.songUploadFields;
    /*Title and SongFile are required to enable the upload button */
    if(name === 'title' && value.length > 0){
      this.setState({uploadButtonToggle: false});
    }else if(name === 'title'){
      this.setState({uploadButtonToggle: true});
    }
    /*don't allow two of the same genre,
    and allow user to subtract genres*/
    if(name === 'genres'){
      var genres = this.state.songUploadFields.genres;;
      if(!this.state.songUploadFields.genres.includes(value)){
        genres.push(value);
        value = genres;
      }else{
        var index = genres.indexOf(value)
        genres.splice(index, 1);
        value = genres;
      }
    //in case of songFile, change 'value' to handle file upload
    }else if(name==='songFile'){
      value = e.target.files[0];
    }
    //update the state
    songUploadFields[name] = value;
    this.setState({songUploadFields});
  }

  handleUpload = () => {
    this.props.onUpload(this.state.songUploadFields);
    this.reset();
  }


  render(){
    return(
      <UploadDropdown
        onUpload={this.handleUpload}
        onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
        data={this.state}
      />
    )
  }
}

export default UploadHandlers
```

and UploadDropdown (only renders this inside a modal):

```
<Uploader
   onUpload={this.props.onUpload}
   onInputChange={this.props.onInputChange}
   data={this.props.data}
/>
```

and uploader:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Form, Button, Input, Dropdown} from 'semantic-ui-react';

/*Uploader is the form for uploading songs */
class Uploader extends React.Component{

  render(){
    const genres = [
      {
        key: 0,
        text: 'world',
        value: 'world',
      },
      {
        key: 1,
        text: 'folk',
        value: 'folk',
      },
      {
        key: 2,
        text: 'psychedelic',
        value: 'psychedelic',
      },
      {
        key: 3,
        text: 'funk',
        value: 'funk',
      },
    ];


    return(
      <div>
        <Form onSubmit={this.props.onUpload}>
          <Form.Field>
            <Input
              name='songFile'
              type="file"
              multiple
              onChange={this.props.onInputChange} />
          </Form.Field>
          <Form.Field>
            <label>Title</label>
            <Input
              type='text'
              name='title'
              placeholder='Title'
              value={this.props.data.songUploadFields.title}
              onChange={this.props.onInputChange}/>
          </Form.Field>
          <Form.Field>
            <label>Description</label>
            <Input
              type='text'
              name='description'
              placeholder='Description'
              value={this.props.data.songUploadFields.description}
              onChange={this.props.onInputChange}/>
          </Form.Field>
          <Form.Field>
            <label>Genres</label>
            <select
              name='genres'
              multiple
              value={this.props.data.songUploadFields.genres}
              onChange={this.props.onInputChange}>
              {genres.map((g, i) => <option key={i} value={g.value}>{g.text}</option>)}
            </select>
          </Form.Field>
          <Button type='submit' disabled={this.props.data.uploadButtonToggle}>Upload</Button>
        </Form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Uploader;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What class is the later code snippet in? Also check all your closing braces.

Comment: To debug your code, you should also log `songData`. Does it have the values you expect?

Comment: My guess is that you don't use immutable objects and you are overwriting the same object with new data.

Comment: Also show the code for `UploadDropdown`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice songData gives expected values. the only other thing that isn't working is the reset() function, it does get called, but state is not set to initialstate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `state` operations keep modifying one set of objects which is shared with the `initialState`, instead of creating new values, for example in:

```
  var genres = this.state.songUploadFields.genres;
  if (!this.state.songUploadFields.genres.includes(value)) {
    genres.push(value);
    value = genres;
  }
```

`genres` is the same object reference as `initialState.songUploadFields.genres`. When you push to it, you are also changing the `initialState`, breaking your `reset` function.

You always need to create a copy, e.g.:

```
var genres = this.state.songUploadFields.genres.slice();
```

The same problem happens with `songUploadFields` object. It is also exactly the same object as in `initialState.songUploadFields`. You need to create a copy before you start to modify it, for example:

```
var songUploadFields = Object.assign({}, this.state.songUploadFields);
```

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time to help out. i didn't realize that's what was happening. this solved all the issues.